# How can I output markup fields or descriptions in my Webform email?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform that requires a markup field, or alternatively, a description to be carried through to the email or "View form submission" page.

Typically one can put the token `%email_values` in the email template which will give a list of fields and their labels that are submitted to the form - but this doesn't seem to include markup fields, or field descriptions.

I have tried using other tokens such as `%post` or `%value`. For instance, I have a markup field with machine name "foo" in a fieldgroup "bar", and putting `%value[foo][bar]` just dumps the string `[foo]` into my email.

So is there a way to reference these parts of the webform?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried using this? If the markup field `foo` sits within the fieldgroup `bar`, you need to inverse the order and the last `%` shouldn't be there.

```
%value[bar][foo]
```